# No Validation takes place When Action Is changed of Form

Tags: php

When i change

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

to

```
 <form method="post" action="whatevername.php">
```

my error messages are not shown and the form doesn't get validate whether it is empty or not.

Comment: If your validation is on the page the form is and not _whatevername.php_ then since the data is being sent to _whatevername.php_ it will of course not execute any code on the current page.

Comment: Should i write my validation code on whatever.php ?

Comment: I have write my validation code in whatever.php still there is no validation taking place the output is empty if the fields are empty in my form.

Comment: Php validation happens after you submit the form, javascript validation happens before the form submits. Depending on your requirements choose the correct one. If you are redirecting the page with the action then doing php validation it'll redirect then validate hence if you want to stop it submitting with empty fields use javascript.

Comment: Okay thanks i will work on it .

Comment: can form data using javascript validation can be send to email id and the amount of data is large of form about 300 characters of one text area

Comment: sorry I don't understand. Are you asking if it is possible to limit the text area to 300 characters?

Comment: no i am asking that i have a textarea which has a limit of 300 characters so when i click submit in my form can i transfer that textarea data fully of 300 characters direclty to an email id ? and if yes please let me know how ?

Comment: So you have a textarea, you want to use javascript to make sure it's not blank, then if javascript accepts the form and submits it then php will email the contents of the textarea to an email? You're losing me on the _transfer textarea directly to an email id_

Comment: i mean to email all the form data to an email id